# Should I use GET or PATCH for requesting info while also updating the resource

Tags: java, spring, api, rest

I am making a Blackjack service in Java using Spring, and i have methods for game moves like Hit, Stand, etc.

My question is, should I use GET or PATCH requests for this? I am asking for the current state of the game in json format, but when i use /hit it also changes the game by adding a card to the player hand. But again, I am still asking info back.

Which one should I use for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET methods should be both **[idempotent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Idempotent)**:

> An HTTP method is idempotent **if an identical request can be made once or several times in a row with the same effect while leaving the server in the same state**. In other words, an idempotent method should not have any side-effects (except for keeping statistics). Implemented correctly, the **GET**, HEAD, PUT, and DELETE **methods are idempotent**

So calling them twice times consecutively should not change the behaviour of calling that method just once.

From what I see it seems that you add a new card each time that you call it, so you change the status after each call, not just after the first call. In this case I would prefer to use a PATCH.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, should I use GET or PATCH requests for this? I am asking for the current state of the game in json format, but when i use /hit it also changes the game by adding a card to the player hand. But again, I am still asking info back.

You normally want to avoid using GET requests that change your resources, because GET is constrained by [safe](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) semantics (aka "effectively read-only"), which means, among other things, that crawlers can freely visit them, and browsers can pre-emptively fetch them "just in case".

So for any action that is expected to modify resources on the server, you should expect an unsafe request method.

[POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post) is most commonly the right choice.  PUT/PATCH can be used for remote authoring when the client is sending to the server a copy of its own local version of a resource.

```
POST /game/12345 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/plain

Hit
```

The payload doesn't have to be text/plain, of course; you could also use application/x-www-form-urlencoded (like forms on the web) or application/json (more common for modern "apis").

The response to the POST request can be an updated copy of the document...

```
200 OK
Content-Location: /game/12345
Content-Type: text/plain

22.  You Lose!
```

---

Note: you normally want the semantics of the message to be in the payload, not in the request target.  So

```
POST /game/12345 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/plain

Hit
```

rather than

```
POST /game/12345/hit HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/plain

Hit
```

because we want the HTTP application to know which resource is changed by the request, so that it can do intelligent things (like update caches).

---

[HTTP PATCH](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5789) isn't *wrong*, necessarily, but its a different idiom.  PATCH, like PUT, is a message we send to tell the server what its resource should look like.

A quick litmus test for using PATCH - are you using a standard/general purpose patch document format?  If not... then you should probably be using POST rather than PATCH.